# Fabric.js. Увеличить оригинал, и сохранить

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Нужно из миниатюрного холста вырезать область, и увеличить. Это работает, на большом canvas всё появляется. 
Не получается сразу же сохранить png. Холст не активный что ли. И картинка пустая.

код тут : https://jsfiddle.net/o9rh58vz/5/ (по отдельности)

```
// увеличить
document.getElementById('big').addEventListener('click',
  function savePNG() {
    //layerNoActive();
    if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
      alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
    }
    else {
      // JSON.stringify(canvas)

      var json = JSON.stringify(canvas);
      canvas2.loadFromJSON(json, canvas2.renderAll.bind(canvas2), function(o, object) {

        if (object.type == 'rect'){
          setActiveProp(object, 'opacity', 0);
        } else {
          var scale = 5;
          var newTop = Math.round( (object.top - canvasAlignTop)*scale,4);
          var newLeft = Math.round( (object.left - canvasAlignLeft)*scale,4);
          // подвинуть
          setActiveProp(object, 'top', newTop);
          setActiveProp(object, 'left', newLeft);

          // увеличить
          setActiveProp(object, 'scaleX', object.scaleX*scale);
          setActiveProp(object, 'scaleY', object.scaleY*scale);
        }


        fabric.log(o, object);
      });

    }
  }
);

// сохранить 
document.getElementById('savePNG').addEventListener('click',
  function printPng(){
    //layerNoActive();
    canvas2.renderAll();
    if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
      alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
    }
    else {
      window.open(canvas2.toDataURL('png'));
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в callback `toDataURL()` вывод положить.